# Validate dropdown list in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have one dropdown in html and i want to validate it using jquery.

```
 Please select your rating * :
    <select id="myDropdown">
    <option value="">-Please Select-</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
    <option value="5">Five</option>
    </select>
```

My Jquery code is like

```
if ($('#myDropdown option:selected').length == 0)
    {
      alert("Please select anyone");
    }
```

What I need is if any value is not selected and it remains like -Please Select- and if the user press submit button, then an alert or any appropriate message needs to be displayed
Please help

Answer (score 6):

```
mydropdown = $('#myDropdown');
if (mydropdown.length == 0 || $(mydropdown).val() == "")
{
    alert("Please select anyone");
}
```

See *Note* below. Also, you don't need the `option:selected` (as per Sly's original answer).

On this fiddle, try selecting another value, then try to select the `-Please Select-` option. You will see the `alert()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/aS2AM/

**EDIT**

*NOTE*: The length test is doing nothing, since it will always report 1, as at least one option is always selected (and your selector is always selecting at least one option, unless the select has no options). I have removed that in this update to the fiddle and code below:

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/LdN6c/3/

You're not capturing the form submit event.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e){ // <<< This selector needs to point to your form.
        if ($('#myDropdown').val() == "") {
            alert("Please select anyone");
            e.preventDefault();
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Note the `#myForm` needs to select your actual form element that contains the selected element.

See in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/LdN6c/1/

Comment: When the page is refreshed, it shows an alert. But when the form is submitted, it is not showing any alert even if the dropdown option is -Please Select-

Comment: This is my Jquery Code now:
$(document).ready(function() {
mydropdown = $('#myDropdown option:selected');
if (mydropdown.length == 0 || $(mydropdown).val() == "")
{
    alert("Please select anyone");
}
});

Comment: ohh..in that answer, drop down change event was not there. Your online program is working fine for me..Thanks Jared

Comment: @sanjeev - See my edit with the submit event handler. Also, if this answers the question for you, please click the check to the right of the answer to select it as the answer. :)

Comment: @sanjeev - You also want to use the submit event handler for this kind of validation (and have a server-side validator in case the JS doesn't function properly).

Comment: @ Jared: The second updation was the one which I was looking. Thank you so much for your patience in responding.

Comment: @sanjeev - See my edit concerning the use of `option:selected`.

Comment: @ Jared: I saw that too. Now I got solution :) Thank you Jared

Comment: @sanjeev - Don't forget to hit the checkmark on the left of the answer. :)

Answer (score -1):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#myForm').submit(function(e) {
        if ($('#myDropdown').val() == '') {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("Please select anyone");
        }
    });
});
```

- Edited with form submit event handler

Comment: Whoever down voted this, I'd just like to point out that the length test doesn't do anything. I didn't realize that until just now, but it always reports 1, since an option is always selected.

Comment: I think it's been downvoted because I didn't provide a full solution. I didn't realized that his problem could be on the form submit event.

Comment: I didn't find that out until his comment, so that would be a poor reason for down voting. I really don't know who down voted, but I think your answer is technically correct.

Comment: No worries, I edited my answer with a more complete solution :)

Comment: Copying my answer into yours is cheesy. You could have just left it as it was, since it did answer the question.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to offense you by improving mine. No stealing intended.